# How to write a factorial function in Javascript using setTimeout or setInterval

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, settimeout, setinterval

I asked a question a couple weeks ago about using setTimeout for a factorial function, but it was unfortunately with an unregistered account and I never got a complete answer.

My main issue is that I'd like to write a function that calculates the factorial of a number but uses the setTimeout or setInterval commands.  The impetus behind this is to reset a counter the IE uses so as to avoid a long-running script warning.  Currently, the factorial function I have is:

```
function factorial(n) {
  return 0 === n || 1 === n ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1)
}
```

In my other post, jsumners was kind enough to provide me with code that tried to use setTimeout periodically when calculating a factorial:

```
function factorial(x) {
 executions++;
   if (x > 1) {
      if (executions % 20 === 0) {
          return (function() {
              var y = x;
              setTimeout(function(y) { return y*factorial(y-1); }, 1);
           });
      } else {
        return x*factorial(x-1);
      }
   } else {
  executions = 0;
      return 1;
   }
}
```

In the above code, it should theoretically use the setTimeout command to perform the next multiplication when the number of elapsed executions is a factor of 20 (mod 20).  Unfortunately, the code does not work, and what happens is that if trying to calculate the factorial of a number greater than 20, then the result is NaN.  If the number is less than 20, then the answer is correct.

Does anyone know of a solution to this or another way to calculate a factorial by using the setTimeout or setInterval commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're specifying `y` as a parameter which is `undefined` when executed because it's not passed in, you can fix it by change this:

```
setTimeout(function(y) { return y*factorial(y-1); }, 1);
```

To this:

```
setTimeout(function() { return y*factorial(y-1); }, 1);
```

However, it'll still be `NaN` because here:

```
      return (function() {
          var y = x;
          setTimeout(function() { return y*factorial(y-1); }, 1);
       });
```

You're still returning a *function*, not a number that can be multiplied, so you still can't use a `setTimeout()` in this manner.  You could pass a callback that executes when everything's done, but you can't have it recurse and return to a caller like this.

Comment: Thanks for breaking down the code for me and letting me know what the issue was.  That said, I should say that I'm an amateur to Javascript, so I'm not quite sure how to to implement a callback as you suggested.  Do I get rid of the 'return' syntax and instead just have the setTimeout command, and then once the multiplier gets down to 1 I then call a callback which returns the answer?  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The callback style factorial with each recurrent step scheduled with setTimeout is:

```
// private helper function (recurrency with accumulation)
function _factorial(acc, n, callback){
  if(n==0){
    callback(acc);
  }else{
    var callback_wrapper = function(result){
       callback(result);
    };
    setTimeout(function(){_factorial(acc * n, n-1, callback_wrapper)}, 10);
  }
}

// public function
function factorial(n, callback){
  _factorial(1, n, callback);
}

// usage example
factorial(10, function(result){console.log(result)});
```

--
Cheers,
Lambder

http://lambder.com/

http://vanadiumJS.com/